# How can I get the value (string) of the current selection in a combobox?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

How can I get the value (string) of the current selection in a combobox?

(Not the integer index)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There might be a better way (my MFC is a bit rusty), but it seems like you should be able to call `CComboBox::GetLBText()`, passing it the current selection using `CComboBox::GetCurSel()`.

Comment: You're probably saying "Hmm" because you were trying to see the new value in a CBN_SELCHANGE handler. That's triggered /before/ the change is committed, but GetLBText does already have access at this point..

Answer (score 9):

A plain old `GetWindowText` works, too.

**Edit:** As ajryan points out, `GetWindowText` actually *doesn't* work in a `CBN_SELCHANGE` handler, because the new selection has taken effect but the window text hasn't been updated with the text of the new selection when the `WM_COMMAND` is sent.

Comment: Hmmm. Looks like you're right. I guess I've never tried that before. A little surprising, because there's usually a "changing" notification for before changes are committed and a "changed" notification for afterward, but that doesn't seem to be the case for combo boxes.

Answer (score 5):

Use GetLBText, passing in the index and a CString object.

edit: too slow!

Answer (score 1):

```
CComboBox   m_CComboBox;
CString currentValue;


m_CComboBox.GetWindowTextA(currentValue);
cout<<"My current Value is: <<currentValue<<endl;
```

Have to work with MFC in 2022 .....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`CB_GETCURSEL` return the integer index
`CB_GETLBTEXT` returns string at `CB_GETCURSEL`

Answer (score 0):

```
char buffer[MAX_COMBO_STRING_LENGTH];

int index= static_cast<int>(SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, ID_COMBO_BOX, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0));
SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, ID_COMBO_BOX, CB_GETLBTEXT, index, (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)buffer);

//buffer contains the selected text unless CB_GETCURSEL returned CB_ERR (-1) to the index
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to this.

---

#### Map to Variable

When you use a combo you can map it to a variable.

- If your combo is a **drop list** it maps to an `int`.
- If your combo is a **drop down** it maps it to a `CString`.

---

#### Direct Acces

As others have said, when your combo is a **drop down** you can think of it as having two the controls (list and edit). Use `GetWindowText` To access the edit control text.

---

#### Using Macros

There are many [helper macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bumper-combobox-control-reference-macros) you can use. And there is one for getting the text ([`ComboBox_GetText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-combobox_gettext) macro). Saves you needing to map control to variable.

It really depends on your needs and usage of the combo control.